# MySQL importing empty date fields

Tags: mysql, csv

I am using MySQL Workbench to import CSV files, some columns have date in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format. However not all of them have entries in the fields, some do and some do not.

On workbench the way it handles these is by throwing an error

```
1264 Out of range value for column "COLUMN NAME HERE"
```

My question is can I tell MySQL to handle these dates before the warning pops up, effectively stopping the huge amount of warnings that appear. I just need it to identify that the field is empty and then initiate the field as "0000-00-00 00:00:00" I know I can set a default but it will still flag a warning.

Comment: since it's a warning does it matter? If you don't want to see them just do this with the mysql command line client and redirect output

Comment: I'd prefer that they didn't. It seems to fill the max amount of warnings that can show at once so if there is another warning I can't see what that is to address it.

Comment: So do it in the command line and do | grep -v 1264

Comment: I did write in my question that I am using MySQL Workbench, that is what I was hoping to address the problem in if at all possible.